# Spring Data Paging And Sorting Repository with multiple fields and date between

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

Below is my entity for the view `vw_invoice_report`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "vw_invoice_report")
class Report implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "sender_name")
    private String sender;

    @Column(name = "client_name")
    private String client;

    @Column(name = "submit_date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date submitDate;

    @Column(name = "invoice_num")
    private String invoiceNum;

    //getters
    }
```

And am trying to implement the `findByClientAndLawfirmAndSubmitDateBetween` to query the view using `client,sender, submitDate` fields

```
public interface ReportRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Report, Long>{
   public List<Report> findByClientAndLawfirmAndSubmitDateBetween(String client, String sender, Date start, Date stop, Pageable pageable)
}
```

when I try to invoke the above method am getting the below error

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: client of: com.xyz.reports.Report 
[select generatedAlias0 from com.xyz.reports.Report as generatedAlias0 where ( ( generatedAlias0.client=:param0 ) and ( generatedAlias0.sender=:param1 ) ) and ( generatedAlias0.submitDate between :param2 and :param3 )]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: client of: com.xyz.reports.Report [select generatedAlias0 from com.xyz.reports.Report as generatedAlias0 where ( ( generatedAlias0.client=:param0 ) and ( generatedAlias0.sender=:param1 ) ) and ( generatedAlias0.submitDate between :param2 and :param3 )] 34178348919273527
```

But if I annotate the above query with `Query` annotation as below  its working fine

```
@Query(value="SELECT id, sender_name, client_name, submit_date, invoice_num FROM vw_invoice_report WHERE client_name  = ?1 AND  sender_name = ?2 AND submit_date BETWEEN ?3 AND ?4 ORDER BY submit_date desc",
        nativeQuery = true)`
```

Is there anyway to make the `findByClientAndLawfirmAndSubmitDateBetween()` work without `@Query`

Comment: Where is ```Lawfirm``` in your entity??

Comment: My bad, that was bad refactoring, `lawfirm` is the `sender` field in `Report` entity

Comment: Was that cause exception??? Are you solved it???

Comment: @RanPaul The identifier type of your `PagingAndSortingRepository` is `Integer` while the `@Id` property is `Long`. Can you check if that causes a problem?

Comment: @Daniel I changed it to `Long` and am still facing the issue

Comment: @윤현구 that didnt solve the issue, am still getting it, I have updated the error message please check

Comment: @RanPaul Then I'd like an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if you can provide one, it's difficult to troubleshoot without more information on your environment.

Comment: I can see your getter?

Answer (score 0):

## Either

Rename property `sender` to `lawFirm`

```
@Column(name = "sender_name")
private String lawfirm;
```

## OR

Rename your repository method to:

```
findByClientAndSenderAndSubmitDateBetween
```